# ThreeJS Adjuste camera rotation

Tags: three.js, camera, rotation

I just want to know how I can rotate this camera ( aerialCamera ) to 180°? I try camera.rotation.y but I think I'm not doing it right.

```
aerialCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80, w/h, 0.1, 1000); 
aerialCamera.position.set(0, 35, 0);
aerialCamera.lookAt( scene.position );
scene.add( aerialCamera );
```

A picture to understand what I would like:
[image: My wish]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `lookAt` requires an `up` vector that points in the direction the top of the camera is facing. The default is `up` is 0, 1, 0 or up but since you're making the camera look straight down the top of the camera (like imagine you actually had a real camera in your hands with a top, front, bottom, back, etc) is not pointing up (toward the sky)

you can fix this in 2 ways

(1) give three.js an [up](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.up) value for the camera

either `camera.up.set(0, 0, 1)` or `camera.up.set(0, 0, -1)`. Then call `camera.lookAt(...)`

(2) don't use look at.

so then `camera.rotation.set(Math.PI / -2, 0, 0)` or `camera.rotation.set(Math.PI / -2, 0, Math.PI)`